# Replace array elements php

Tags: php

Is it possible to replace and array with another?

```
$databas= array("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4");
$replace_datbas= array("Estimate","Market","Assesments","Products");

foreach($databas as $data){
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM doc WHERE $data='1')"

  foreach($replace_databas as $replace_data){



    $data=$replace_data


    echo"$data";
  }
}
```

**Edit**
i need to replace the array inside foreach loop becouse i cant do it before it since i need the $database array to my mysql_query before i can replace it.

Comment: Without context, `$databas = $replace_datbase;`?

Comment: From where you want to replace the array values ?

Comment: Inside the foreach loop if it is possible, i need first array for mysql_query but i dont want to print out the first array to users tho.

Comment: @user3616064 Please provide a full source of you have and what you need till we be able to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use reference:

```
$database = array("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4");
$replace_datbase = array("Estimate","Market","Assesments","Products");
foreach($database as &$data){
    foreach($replace_datbase as $replace_data){
        $data = $replace_data;
    }
}
```

but probably you meant this (that inner foreach above does not make sense - `$data` value will be always last value from `$replace_database`):

```
$database = array("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4");
$replace_datbase = array("Estimate","Market","Assesments","Products");
foreach($database as $index => &$data){
    $data = $replace_data[$index];
}
```

Comment: First one will just produce an array where all values are `Products` (i.e. `array_fill(0, count($databas), 'Product')`). The second one is equivalent to `$databas = $replace_datbase;`.

Comment: I wrote that first one does not make sense - just don't know what OP meant. Second one is not exactly what you wrote. It'll replace array values not whole array.

Comment: Which is effectively the same as replacing the entire array.

Comment: my first array is names from mysql table which are must for mysq_query to work, but i dont want to print out first array to users becouse it dosent make sense to them so im trying to replace the first array with second one after mysql_query to make it more user friendly.

Comment: @AmalMurali that really depends - if that code would be a body of function like `function mysomething(&$database) {...` it would not be the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use as follows:

```
foreach($databas as $key=>$data)
{
    $databas[$key] = $replace_databas[$key];
}
```

Comment: Or you could just write `$databas = $replace_datbase;`.

Comment: this is wrong, since the key will not allways be a numeric value

Comment: I was thinking it is for study purposes (he might add conditions and etc), I also assumed that the keys will always be numeric (as given)

Answer (score 0):

```
$databas = $replace_datbas;
```

Either I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, or you're making this way too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_replace

```
$databas= array("data1", "data2", "data3", "data4");
$replace_datbas= array("Estimate","Market","Assesments","Products");

$result = array_replace($dtabas, $replace_databas);
```

Keep in mind that this *replaces the values of first array with values of second array having the same keys*